# What blessing does one make on non-kosher food?

Tags: halacha, blessing, kashrut-kosher, mysticism-kabbalah

Is a blessing made on *non-kosher* food that one is normally forbidden (אסור) to eat when one is in an exceptional circumstance? *(like for example, starving and without other food)* The food becomes *permissible* (מותר) through the unusual circumstance, but is still non-kosher.

To clarify my terminology, according to the kabbalistic understanding of food, ***Kosher Food*** comes from what is called *Klipat Nogah* according to kabbalistic teaching. Klipat Nogah is a mixture of **Tov** and **Ra**.

***Non-Kosher Food*** comes from the three, completely unfit Klipot which, as is taught in the Tanya and elsewhere, contain no Tov whatsoever.

Normally, a blessing over food with Shem and Malchut is said over something that is permissible (not *Assur*) and that also has Tov to elevate (what is called the *Spark of Holiness*). This is the meaning of the verse, *"Ishei rei'ach nicho'ach l'HaShem"*.

In this case, the food is permitted, but it still originates from the three completely unfit Klipot.

Is it the regular blessing for that general type/category of food (meat, bread, wine, fruit, etc) or something else?

The usual blessing on *permitted food* includes Shem & Malchut, which means that what you recite over has specific requirements from Chazal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87043/discussion-on-question-by-yaacov-deane-what-blessing-does-one-make-on-n0n-kosher).